# How can i get forwarder message name python pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, api, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

So, when forwarding a message to the bot from another user, bot should get original **forward sender name**

I tried like in documentation:

`reply_to_id = message.forward_sender_name`

but i got this error:
 `'Message' object has no attribute 'forward_sender_name'`

Can i get users original first_name from forwarded message?

I am using **python 3.7 pytelegrambotapi**

Answer (score 0):

You go through Telegram Bot API documentation. In pyTelegramBotAPI Use `forward_from` instead of `message.forward_sender_name`.

```
reply_to_id = message.forward_from.first_name + messge.forward_from.last_name
```